# Is there an API or something similar to respond to human language?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots, chatroom

I've written a chat room bot for Campfire and it is programmed to handle certain keywords and commands, however I'd like to make it seem more sentient.

Is there an API that can take a string such as:

'Are you a robot?'

and respond with something like:

'Of course not.'

? Or even a linux program or bit of open source software that can do something like that?

I'd rather not write one from scratch!

Comment: I'm afraid resource requests are not acceptable here...

Comment: Thanks Jan. Would you mind telling me where I should go to ask such a question? Perhaps I sound too much like a freeloader? I have used ReactPHP to write a library that interfaces with BaseCamp's campfire API which I'm planning on opening up on github very soon.

Comment: I don't know of such a place; sorry about that. Please check [area51.se] if there's such a site in proposal.

Comment: Off-topic apparently. Can anyone suggest where I should ask this question? :/

Answer (score 2):

There is a python package called [chat](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.chat.html) from [nltk](http://nltk.org/index.html) where you can have a 'conversation' with different bots. You could take these codes and build on them for your own application.

Comment: And of course these days there is GTP-3 of course.